# Dúvida Sequelize Node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

Em relação ao `sequelize` eu criei uma table no meu pgadmin com o nome de `TB_USER` mas estou com uma dúvida ao criar o model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/dataBase');

const Users = db.define('users', {
    title:{
        type: Sequelize
    }
})
```

Em relação ao `db.define('users'` eu teria que colocar o nome da tabela que eu criei? Se eu não colocar o `sequelize` irá criar essa table users?

Comment: Sim, o Sequelize vai criar a tabela, no seu caso, 'userss' com mais um 's' no final, pois por padrao, o Sequelize pluraliza o nome de todas as tabelas criadas.

Comment: @CmteCardeal vlw mano, se você quiser adicionar uma resposta eu dou voto nela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, o Sequelize vai criar a tabela, no seu caso, `userss` com mais um `s` no final, pois por padrão, o Sequelize pluraliza o nome de todas as tabelas criadas.

Para deixar o nome da tabela no singular, você pode passar um terceiro objeto no metodo `define` com o atributo `freezeTableName` com valor `true`.

```
const Users = db.define('users', {
 title: {
    type: Sequelize.String
 }
}, { freezeTableName: true });
```